# Dependency 'com.graphql-java:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2' not found

Tags: graphql-js, graphql-java

i am trying to implement graphql using java spring boot. i cannot add dependency `graphiql-spring-boot-starter`. The error message is

> Dependency 'com.graphql-java:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2' not found

[image]

i am expecting solution to the error

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a typo: `graphql-spring-boot-starter` instead of `graphiql-spring-boot-starter`.